# signal clicked on a header of a Qtreewidget

Tags: pyqt, qtreewidget

which is the signal when i click on an header of a QwidgetItem?

```
self.head = self.treeWidget.headerItem()
self.head.itemClicked.connect(self.customSortByColumn)
```

dont work

Answer (score 1):

QTreeWidgetItem doesn't have such a signal.

You should take a look at

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html

and

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#signals

QHeaderView offers a signal 'sectionClicked'.

This might help you.

```
  self.head = self.treeWidget.header() # gets the QHeaderView
  self.head.sectionClicked.connect(self.customSortByColumn)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try the following:

```
header()->setSectionsClickable(true);
```

This is from Qt(c++)

In pyqt, it may be the same